# sequelize migration not work properly

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

config.json file is Database connection file in sequelize. In my project **config.json** file have group of database

**config.json** look like:

```
{ 
  "TEST_CS": {
    "development": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "databaseOne",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": "3306",
      "logging": true,
      "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "test": {
      "dialect": "sqlite",
      "storage": ":memory:"
    },
    "production": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "databaseTwo",
      "host": "localhost",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    }
  },
    "CS_SERVER": {
    "development": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "My_db",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": "3306",
      "logging": true,
      "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "test": {
      "dialect": "sqlite",
      "storage": ":memory:"
    },
    "production": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "databaseFour",
      "host": "localhost",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    }
   }

}
```

Throw following error:

Loaded configuration file "models\config\config.json".

ERROR: Dialect needs to be explicitly supplied as of v4.0.0

But when i remove object of json in **config.json** file. migration done properly

```
{ 
  //Remove CS_SERVER object
    "development": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "My_db",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": "3306",
      "logging": true,
      "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "test": {
      "dialect": "sqlite",
      "storage": ":memory:"
    },
    "production": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "password",
      "database": "database_production",
      "host": "localhost",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    }

}
```

How to access array of json in **config.json** file  in sequelize migration

Comment: Can you share the code where you are making connection with database i.e. where you are using this file?

Comment: with In model folder

**config file( with in config file "config.json" located)

**CS_SERVER file

**migrations file

**TEST_CS file

**index.js ( main sequelize file)

Comment: Please post the code for your index.js where you initialise sequelize

Answer (score 1):

While making the connection only this object is required

```
{
  "username": "root",
  "password": "password",
  "database": "My_db",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "3306",
  "logging": true,
  "dialect": "mysql"
}
```

development, test, and production are keys which are used to choose according to the environment variable.

But if you're using TEST_CS or CS_SERVER then you have to pass these key manually when making the connection like this.

```
let config    = require('../serverconfig/config.json')['CS_SERVER'][env];
let sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul . but .sequelizerc file by default  call the development key in config.json file.